# UITextView text blocks are cutting off

Tags: iphone, uitextview, ios-simulator, ios13

My TextView blocks are cutting of on an iPad/iPhone IOS 13 and higher. The width size of the UITextView object = 512 and I don't use constrains. In the simulator Version 11.3.1 it works fine.

I generate a lot of reports...

Before I make a PDF file of the view the following code is executed:
 [p04_Paragraph_01 sizeToFit] ;

p04_Paragraph_01 is a UITextView object.

If I check the UIView details where the textview object is located I see the width size of 512 and that is correct.

What happens? Thanks for your help!

In IOS 12 it works fine!

[iPhone PDF output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kU8i6.png)

[Simulator PDF output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7d0M.png)

Comment: If I change the font size (from 20 to 14) of the uitextview the first uitextview is then correct. I've three uitextview objects on the same view. The text is cutting off on the other 2 objects if I change also there font sizes (20 to 14 or 20). It's a strange behaviour of this new IOS 13 release.

Comment: This is solved in ios in release 13.5.